# What's the easiest way to remove the "total <size>" line from the output of ls -l?

Tags: ls

The best I could find via Google/`man ls` was:

```
ls -l | grep -v '^total'
```

Is there something I'm missing in the flags to `ls`?

<del>Also, why is the total size in kb, regardless of the -h flag?</del> scratch that, seems like it does, not sure what I was seeing then.

Comment: Perhaps a little bit more efficient could be `ls -l | tail -n+2`, for the rest I do not have an answer.

Comment: I like enzotib's method more. Suggestion: set it up as an alias and name it `lsl`. Just 3 letters ;) oh and ls -lh shows me 1.2K styled sizes.

Comment: I think you've gotten the easiest way.

Comment: Lots of good suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7318497/9210961) for the general case of removing any first line of an output

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Looking in the source code of `coreutils`, I found out that `total` will always be displayed when using the `-l` option on *directories*.

Using the `-d` option to list entries instead of directory contents hides `total`. But if you run that without arguments (or on a directory), it'll just show the directory and not its contents. Therefore, you need wildcards. `*` matches all files and `.*` matches hidden files as well (which corresponds with the `-a` option):

```
ls -ld * .*
```

As for the `-h` option, it works for me. 1118360 bytes show up as 1.1M. Files smaller than 1024 show up in bytes.

Comment: actually -d lists directories instead of entries.

Comment: @broiyan You can take the `ls` manual page to the letter or consider this: `ls /` can be interpreted as "list the entry `/` if it is a file or the directory contents of `/` if it is a directory". Using `-d` removes the last condition and will always print the entry instead of directory contents. This applies no matter if a path is a file or directory.

Comment: I'd upvote this again if i could

Answer (score 10):

Using wildcards to avoid having `ls` running the directory listing is suboptimal, because it prevents you from using `ls` options like `--almost-all`.

Like [Enzotib's suggestion](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61177/whats-the-easiest-way-to-remove-the-total-size-line-from-the-output-of-ls#comment70022_61177), the simplest way to remove it is to pipe it through `tail` to chop off the first line. However, `ls` will detect that it its output is a pipe rather than interactive, and change its defaults in an unwanted way. Hence, to make it robust, you should also add some options:

- `--color=always`: keep showing colors
- `--hide-control-chars`: print `?` in filenames in place of control characters that could mess up the console output

I have a script `~/bin/l` (you could also use a Bash alias in `~/.bash_aliases`):

```
#!/bin/bash
ls -l --color=always --hide-control-chars "$@" | tail --lines=+2
```

You can also add any other `ls` options you want by default, e.g. `--group-directories-first --time-style='+%FT%T.%N%:::z' --indicator-style=slash`.

Comment: However, this won't work if you if you pass multiple filenames to ls.

Answer (score 4):

`ls -l *`

Will give you "normally named" folder contents without the `total`.  That might be suitable for your needs.  Unfortunately, it will not give you the `dot` prefixed files.  If you use `ls -l * .*` you will get a mess since linux will navigate up the tree.

Note the dot prefix could mean the folder or with a wildcard it means the above folder so it does not help you to pick regular files that are dot prefixed.  This seems to have been an unfortunate design decision.

Comment: Even `ls -l *` will list contents of the directories, not the directories themselves.

Answer (score 3):

> `$ ls -l [DIRECTORY] | sed 1d` 
>  (output contains file names)
>
> `$ ls -ld [path-to-dir]/*` 
>  (output contains relative paths but will
>   preserve colors)
>
> `$ ls -l [DIRECTORY] | tail -n +2`
>
> `$ ls -l [DIRECTORY] | awk 'NR>=1'`

---

**Note:** 
The following doesn't work if you have a file named "total...."

> `$ ls -l | grep -v '^total'`

Comment: ...or if you have a non-English locale: `LANG=ja_JP.utf8 ls -al | head -n 1` (given that the locale is installed).

Answer (score 1):

To answer your exact question would be `ls -1A .` which displays files, directories, and hidden files/directories, does not use any pipes or external tools (grep/tr/cut..), and does not rely on turning on or off any shell globbing options such as extglob, globstar, or nullglob. I have tested it to verify that statement.

```
-1    list one file per line.  Avoid '\n' with -q or -b
-A,   --almost-all           do not list implied . and ..
```

Example output:

```
user@host:/dir$ ls -1A .
temp
terraform
.test
tor
torrent-stuff
.Trash-1000
virtual_appliance
visualblind
vpn-ipv4.txt
vpn-ipv6.txt
zztestfile
.zztestfile2
```

As a side note, here is what I keep in my .bash_aliases relating to listing dirs/files:

```
# ls directories
alias lsd2='ls -d */'
alias lsd3='ls -p . | grep -E "/$" | tr -d "/"'
alias lsd4='ls -lA | grep -E "^d"'
alias lsd5='ls -pv . | grep -E "/$" | tr -d "/"'
alias lsd='ls -lAd */'
# ls files
alias lsf='ls -pA | grep -vE "/$"'
alias lsf2='ls -p | grep -v "/"'
alias lsf3='ls -p . | grep "/" | tr -d "/"'
alias lsf4='ls -lA | grep -vE "^d"'
# ls normal
alias lsnormal='ls -lAh1d *'
alias lsnormal2='ls -1 .'
```

Answer (score 0):

ls does not seem to accept `R` parameter when `-1` is specified.
It also does not take location argument (if you are in the `/home` directory, the command will not return `/` root content)

```
sudo ls -l1diR *
     13 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root     7 Հլս  8 23:58 bin -> usr/bin
 131073 drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4096 Հլս  9 00:30 boot
2228225 drwxrwxr-x   2 root root  4096 Հլս  9 00:00 cdrom
      1 drwxr-xr-x  21 root root  4300 Հլս 12 08:46 dev
1572865 drwxr-xr-x 140 root root 12288 Հլս 12 09:06 etc
1179649 drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Հլս  9 00:01 home
     14 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root     7 Հլս  8 23:58 lib -> usr/lib
     15 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root     9 Հլս  8 23:58 lib32 -> usr/lib32
     16 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root     9 Հլս  8 23:58 lib64 -> usr/lib64
     17 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    10 Հլս  8 23:58 libx32 -> usr/libx32
     11 drwx------   2 root root 16384 Հլս  8 23:58 lost+found
 524289 drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Հլս  9 00:11 media
 262145 drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Ապր 15 03:27 mnt
2097153 drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4096 Հլս 10 01:39 opt
      1 dr-xr-xr-x 325 root root     0 Հլս 12 08:46 proc
1310721 drwx------   4 root root  4096 Հլս  9 10:36 root
      1 drwxr-xr-x  35 root root   940 Հլս 12 09:07 run
     18 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root     8 Հլս  8 23:58 sbin -> usr/sbin
 393217 drwxr-xr-x  11 root root  4096 Հլս 10 01:25 snap
1835009 drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Ապր 15 03:27 srv
      1 dr-xr-xr-x  13 root root     0 Հլս 12 08:46 sys
1966081 drwxrwxrwt  19 root root  4096 Հլս 12 09:09 tmp
1310722 drwxr-xr-x  14 root root  4096 Ապր 15 03:27 usr
 655361 drwxr-xr-x  14 root root  4096 Ապր 15 03:32 var
```